# Archive page of taxonomy returns a 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I'm trying to create a template file for a custom taxonomy archive page but I keep getting a 404 error when trying to access that archive page.

Basically something like: domain.com/quizzes/quiz-levels/

I managed to create template files for /quizzes/ and /b1-intermediate/ (or whatever the level is), but when I land on "domain.com/quizzes/quiz-levels/" I get a 404 error doesn't take any template file.

What I'm aiming for is the following:

- domain.com/quizzes/ : To show all the quizzes (Works)
- domain.com/quiz-post-slug/ : To show the quiz post (Works)
- domain.com/quiz-levels/a1-beginner/ : To show quizzes belonging to this level (works)
- domain.com/quiz-levels Or domain.com/quizzes/quiz-levels/ : To show the available levels (Doesn't work).

```php
function quiz_custom_post_type() {
  $args = array(
          'labels'                => array(
                                            'name' => 'Quizzes',
                                            'singular_name' => 'Quiz'
                                  ),
          'public'                => true,
          'has_archive'           => true,
          'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-editor-spellcheck',
          'menu_position'         => 4,
          'has_archive'           => true,
          'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'comments'),
          'show_in_rest'          => true,
          'rest_base'             => 'quizzes',
          'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller'
          
  );
  register_post_type('quizzes', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'quiz_custom_post_type');


function quiz_levels_taxonomy() {

  $args = array(
                'labels' => array(
                                  'name'          => 'Levels',
                                  'singular_name' => 'Level',
                                  'add_new_item'  => 'Add New Level'
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'quiz-levels')
  );
  register_taxonomy('levels', array('quizzes'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'quiz_levels_taxonomy');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you flushed permalinks? Is `quizzes/quiz-levels/b1-intermediate/` a quizzes post with the slug `b1-intermediate`? Or a term? It's unclear, I also don't see the names of your templates though that shouldn't matter, if it didn't find them it would fallback to a more generic template until it reached `index.php`. The 404 is that it did not find the content, not that it didn't find the theme template

Comment: Yes I did flush the permalinks, and that didn't change anything. "b1-intermediate" is basically a taxonomy item under which there are supposed to be posts (quizzes). Quizzes are displayed after the custom post slug like (domain.com/quizzes/post-slug

Comment: I edited to correct something and provide more details if that helps.

Comment: @Badr "domain.com/quiz-post-slug" - I think you meant `domain.com/quizzes/quiz-post-slug` ? And taxonomies do not have an "all-terms/any-terms archive" (only specific terms in that taxonomy have an archive which commonly displays posts in that specific term), hence `domain.com/quiz-levels` would by default show a 404 error page. But to make `domain.com/quiz-levels` works, one way would be - add a static Page (post type `page`) and set the slug to `quiz-levels`, then just display whatever you want to..

Comment: is this a URL you constructed yourself or a URL provided as a link by WordPress? Just to re-iterate, your template file has nothing to do with wether WP finds posts or not and generates a 404, the query/posts determines the template, not the other way around, and WP already knows what posts to display before a template is even chosen

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes you're correct, I meant domain.com/quizzes/quiz-post-slug Thank you for your clarification, I understand now and went with your suggestion.

Comment: @TomJNowell It's a URL I constructed myself. I don't think it's a template issue because wp would fall back to index.php when it doesn't find an appropriate template file for the page.

Comment: @Badr that's problematic, you need to use the correct permalink, what WP will give you, and then if that differs you need to work towards changing that, _not_ constructing a URL by hand. If you get the answer to your question you're going to run into a brand new problem of WP redirecting the canonical URL because of this. Make sure to edit your question to clarify these things clearly using the edit link, not everybody will read the comments